# I’m looking for a way to find all orders that the "bill to" and "ship to" are different states and the dollar amounts associated with those orders

Tags: database, magento-1, sales-order, join, statistics

I know that I could check in the sales flat tables. I would probably have to look into `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_address` and do a SQL join.

Additionally, the `entity_id` would be the related column.

Does anybody have a definitive way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know is it a what you mean by a "definitive way", but here is a SQL for your purpose:

```
SELECT sfo.`entity_id`, sfo.`base_grand_total`, sfoas.`region` AS `shipping_region`, sfoab.`region` AS `billing_region` FROM `sales_flat_order` as `sfo`
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `sfoas` ON sfo.`entity_id` = sfoas.`parent_id` AND sfo.`shipping_address_id` = sfoas.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `sfoab` ON sfo.`entity_id` = sfoab.`parent_id` AND sfo.`billing_address_id` = sfoab.`entity_id`
WHERE sfoas.`region` <> sfoab.`region`
```

Result in phpmyadmin:

[image: result in phpmyadmin]

Comment: Thank you very much Siarhey, this is just what i needed.

Comment: Is there an easy way to add another 'where' clause for a specific year. Like where sfo created_at = "2017" ?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks again Siarhey!

Comment: @thismethod I'm glad to help you :)